# Show "Go" menu item in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In previous versions of Windows, Windows Explorer had the "Go" menu item in the pull-down menus (between "Edit" and "View"). In Windows 7 there is no such item. Is it possible to restore it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "Go" entry has been moved inside the "View" menu.